# Google places error in React 16 after upgrade from 15.x

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I just upgraded my React app to React 16.0 from 15.x and now getting the following error. The code itself did not change other than the fact that it's now a React 16.0 app.

> 'google' is not defined  no-undef

I use the auto complete feature in a util method I created as follows:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
const googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
const googlePlacesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

export const googlePlacesAutoComplete = (keyword, callback) => {

    googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, (predictions, status) => {

        if(status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) return callback(null);
        return callback(predictions);
    });
}
```

I simply point to Google Places libraries from the static HTML page for my React app's entry point.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=my-api-key"></script>
```

Any idea what's wrong? Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ’window.google’?
’google’ is global and it is recommend not to use globals as is.

Also, if you can, try to add ’google’ as a module to ensure it as veen loaded before use.
And possibly avoid a global variable or anything could override its value.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. Thank you!